# Calculate a Running Total plus minus with merge column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a table with five column description, opening balance, sale, sale return, recipt.

I want to merge opening balance, sale as "Debit" and salereturn, recipt as "Credit".

How to calculate running total as column name as "balance" debit amount plus and credit amount MINUS in balance column?

[image: SEE TABLE STRACTURE AND PROBLEM IN JPG]

My attempt is

SELECT Description, (InvoiceAmount + OpeningBalance) as 'Dabit', (DrAmount + SaleReturn + BadDebtAmount) as 'credit', SUM (sale+ OpeningBalance-SaleReturn-recipt) over (ORDER BY id) AS RunningAgeTotal FROM tablename

Comment: SELECT Description, (InvoiceAmount + OpeningBalance) as 'Dabit', (DrAmount + SaleReturn + BadDebtAmount) as 'credit', SUM (sale+ OpeningBalance-SaleReturn-recipt) over (ORDER BY id) AS RunningAgeTotal FROM tablename

Comment: Please [edit] any additional info directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing `coalesce()` and a window function:

```
select description,
       coalesce(opening, sale) as debit,
       coalesce(return, receipt) as credit,
       sum(coalesce(opening, sale, 0) - coalesce(return, receipt,  0)) over (order by order by (case description when 'opening balance' then 1 when 'sale' then 2 when 'sale return' then 3 else 4 end))
from t
order by (case description when 'opening balance' then 1 when 'sale' then 2 when 'sale return' then 3 else 4 end);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the expense of creating a temporary list, a Linq version would be as follows :

Assuming your original source is from a Sql database, then you first need to bring the data into memory, eg

```
var records = OrderDetails
    .OrderBy(a=>a.Date)
    .Select(a => new 
    {
        a.Description,
        Debit = a.OpeningBalance + a.Sale,
        Credit = a.Return + a.SaleReturn
    }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Note the query needs to be sorted to ensure the date is returned in the correct order. You haven't mentioned any other fields, so I have just assumed there is a field called date that can be used.

Once you have the data in memory, you can then add the Balance column, ie

```
decimal balance = 0;
var list = records.Select(a => new
{
    a.Description,
    a.Debit,
    a.Credit,
    Balance =  balance +=  (a.Debit - a.Credit),
}).ToList();
```

Because you are introducing a local variable and initialising it outside the Linq statement, it is important that the query is not enumerated twice unless balance has been reset to zero. You can avoid this by using `.ToList();` or `.ToArray();`

Comment: Could not understand

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: decimal balance = 0;
            var list = _context.InvoiceTransation.Select(a => new
            {
                a.Description,
                a.Dr,
                a.Cr,          

                Balance = balance += (a.Dr - a.Cr),
            }).ToList();
            Error is An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator
            at this  line
                 Balance = balance += (a.Dr - a.Cr)

Comment: This only works for in memory objects (Linq To Entities). I know your original data comes from SQL, but I assumed your second stage (where you merge the columns in Debit/Credit) would bring the results in memory. I'll update the answer to reflect this.